# Check if table a primary key is exist in table b

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js

Table A: 
ID, Name,  etc.

Table B:
ID, TableA-ID.

```
SELECT * FROM A;
```

and I want to return a boolean value in the same result for this condition ( if A.ID Exists in Table B).

Comment: Edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select A.*, IFNULL((select 1 from B where B.TableA-ID = A.ID limit 1),0) as `exists` from A;
```

The above statement will result in a 1, if the key exists, and a 0 if that key does not exist.  Limit 1 is important if there are multiple records in B

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 3):

There are several ways of achieving what you need. Below are three possibilities. These all differ in execution plans and how database actually wants to execute them so depending on your record count one may be more efficient than the other. It's better if you see it for yourself.

---

**1)** Use `LEFT JOIN` and check if a non-null field from B is not null to ensure the record exists. Then apply `DISTINCT` clause if relationship is 1:N to only show rows from A without duplicates.

```
select distinct a.*, b.id is not null as exists_b
from a
left join b on
  a.id = b.tablea-id
```

---

**2)** Use `exists()` function, which will be evaluated for each row being returned from table A.

```
select a.*, exists(select 1 from b where a.id = b.tablea-id) as exists_b
from a
```

---

**3)** Use a combination of subquery expression `EXISTS` and it's contradiction in two queries to check if a record has or has not a match within table B. Then `UNION ALL` to combine both results into one.

```
select *, true as exists_b
from a
where exists (
  select 1
  from b
  where a.id = b.tablea-id
  )
union all
select *, false as exists_b
from a
where not exists (
  select 1
  from b
  where a.id = b.tablea-id
  )
```

Comment: Thank you very much